# Termux | NO_PUBKEY B0076E490B71616B

Tags: termux

Если я хочу обновить пакеты через `apt update`, воходит ошибка

```
W: GPG error: https://grimler.se/termux-packages-24 stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B0076E490B71616B
E: The repository 'https://grimler.se/termux-packages-24 stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now.
N: Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).
```

Я устанавливал Termux из Fdroid.

Answer (score 0):

Обнови `termux-keyring` до версии 3.9-1:

```
curl https://packages.termux.dev/apt/termux-main/pool/main/t/termux-keyring/termux-keyring_3.9-1_all.deb -o termux-keyring.deb && dpkg -i termux-keyring.deb
```